# How can I define a function that returns a function?

Tags: go

I am new in Go. I need to define a function that returns a function. The first function defines a polynomial and resturns it as a result and the second function uses the result of the first function to compute another result.

```
func calculateThis (x *big.Int) (********) { // I need to replace the ******** with the correct type

a := new(big.Int).Mult(x, Y)
B := a.Add(a, big.NewInt(1))

}
// return B
```

I need here to return the function (x.Y + 1) as a result where Y is a value that will be defined by another function.

How can I complete the function definition?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite get what your code is supposed to be doing, but here is a function that returns another function:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func adder(x int) func(y int) int {
    return func(y int) int {
        return x + y
    }
}
func main() {
  add5 := adder(5)
  fmt.Println(add5(3))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CWgLt6HYENH)

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact, I need a code that generates a function or a result in the form of a polynomial where y is not used in the actual code but the result contains this y. A nother function whill get this polynomial as input and uses it to generates another result. So,  they will be two functions: one that defines the function and one that uses it to generates another result.